# How to loop only a part of list given an index

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to loop a list in three parts, given indexes, for instance "0,1,2" I need to loop a list from 0 to 1/3, from 1/3 to 2/3 and 2/3 to 3/3 part of a list but I don't know how to do it

I tried this but obviusly, it is not correct:

```
def mapping(index, list_all_words, n_threads):
    list_of_ones = []
    for i in range( 0 , (index/n_threads) * len(list_all_words)):
        # do some stuff
```

Comment: Would the indexes ever be anything other than 1,2, ... n_threads? In other words, do you just want to split the list into `n_threads` equal parts (or as equal as you can make it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that:

```
index = 0
n_threads = 3
list_all_words = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7"]
for i in range( int((index / n_threads) * len(list_all_words)), int(((index + 1) /n_threads) * len(list_all_words))):
    print(list_all_words[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def split(a, n):  # function to split a list in n even parts
    k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
    return list((a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n)))

list_all_words = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7"]
new_lists = split(list_all_words, 3) # split into 3 parts as equally as possible
for lst in new_lists:
    print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
['test4', 'test5']
['test6', 'test7']
```

Instead of having function `split` create a list of lists, you can have it return a *generator expression* that will create the lists as you iterate the expression, which saves memory. This is accomplished by changing the last line to:

```py
    return (a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n))
```